# Vuelidate: multiple Step form validation

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

I'm using Vuelidate for my form validation.

It is a multiple-step form, but in the step 2 which there isn't input to valid, when I clicked next step button, I can't go to the step 3.

What may be wrong with my code?

```
    <section v-show="step === 1">
        <h3>Step 1</h3>
        <div class="name">
            <h4>Name</h4>
            <input v-model="name" @blur="$v.name.$touch" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg">
            <p v-if="$v.name.$error" class="error-msg">Please fill the name</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section v-show="step === 2" class="step2">
        <h3>Step 2</h3>
        ...
    </section>
    
    <section v-show="step === 3" class="step3">
        <h3>Step 3</h3>
            <div class="tele">
                <label for="contact-tele">Telephone</label>
                <input v-model="phone" @blur="$v.phone.$touch" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                <p v-if="$v.phone.$error" class="error-msg">Please fill your telephone number</p>
            </div>
    </section>

<button class="next-step no-print" @click.prevent="nextStep" v-if="step != totalSteps>Next Step</button>
```

My vue code

```
methods: {
        nextStep: function() {
            if (this.step = 1) {
                if (this.$v.name.$invalid) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return this.step = 2;
                }
            }

            if (this.step = 3) {
                if (this.$v.phone.$invalid) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return this.step = 3;
                }
            }
            this.step++;
        },
   
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are using a single `=` that assigns to `this.step` the values that you want to check for (1 and 3), while you should use a triple `===` to check the value.

```
//if (this.step = 1) {
if (this.step === 1) {
    if (this.$v.name.$invalid) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return this.step = 2;
    }
}

//if (this.step = 3) {
if (this.step === 3) {
    if (this.$v.phone.$invalid) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return this.step = 3;
    }
}
this.step++;
```

Read more bout the difference between `=`, `==` & `===`[here](https://www.guru99.com/difference-equality-strict-operator-javascript.html#:%7E:text=KEY%20DIFFERENCES%3A,datatype%20and%20compares%20two%20values.).

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you! So what's the logic behind it?

Comment: Is just the normal way js works. One = assign, two == check (not types), three === check with types. Read more here: https://www.guru99.com/difference-equality-strict-operator-javascript.html#:~:text=KEY%20DIFFERENCES%3A,datatype%20and%20compares%20two%20values.

and please mark as answered

Answer (score 0):

use `===` in the condition instead of `=`.

```
if(this.step === 1)
```

and also try to avoid the else case as you are having the `this.step++` in the end. It will increment the step.

```
if (this.step = 1 && this.$v.name.$invalid) return false

if (this.step = 3 && this.$v.phone.$invalid) return false

this.step++;
```